# Pushbullet curl send to channel how?

Tags: curl, pushbullet

How can I send to channel?

This is the code I use for notes:

```
curl -k https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/pushes -X POST -u <MYTOKEN>: --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary "{\"type\": \"note\", \"title\":\"Note Title\", \"body\": \"Note Body\"}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the "channel_tag" parameter in the body of the message there: https://docs.pushbullet.com/#create-push

Comment: do you have an example ?? i dont understand it , how can i put it in my line ?

Comment: Something like this should work: "{\"type\": \"note\", \"title\":\"Note Title\", \"body\": \"Note Body\", \"channel_tag\": \"tag\"}"

Comment: i get thi error {"error":{"code":"invalid_param","type":"invalid_request","message":"The param '
channel_tag' has an invalid value.","param":"channel_tag","cat":"\u003e:3"}}

Comment: Your channel_tag may not point to a channel that exists and that you own.